# Borderless PDF saving from website

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, printing

I'm trying to save a website as a PDF file using the `File -> Print...`. The PDF preview has a white border all around, as does the final final PDF product. I've followed the steps suggested on [this website](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6860728), but that doesn't work. Other websites suggest using `File -> Page Setup`, but that option no longer exists in later versions of macOS.

I'm using Safari 11.0.3 on macOS 10.13.3.

How can I force the PDF file not to have any white borders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the border is a part of the PDF document itself, in which case it's not an issue with printing preferences. The easiest solution is to crop the PDF in Preview, then print it.

Instead of **File > Print**, perform **File > Export as PDF (or Save as)**.

**[Open the PDF in Preview and crop it](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/crop-or-rotate-a-pdf-prvw11567/mac).**

From the above Apple support article:

> If the Markup toolbar isn’t showing, click the Show Markup Toolbar
> button , then click the Rectangular Selection button .
>
> Select the portion of the page you want to keep.
>
> Click the Crop button in the Markup toolbar (or use the Touch Bar).

Once you select the portion, you can alternatively the shortcut <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to crop it as well.

Once you are finished, save the PDF if you wish and print it.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts. Exporting as PDF works rather nicely.

Comment: What should I do on Chrome? That doesn't have an exporting option...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work on certain macOS or configuration you're using. But on my setup I get a borderless PDF with these steps:

1. Create a borderless paper size as described in [the website](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6860728) you've mentioned.
2. Have the borderless paper size set as the default one in System Preferences > Printers & Scanners > Default paper size.
3. Now that when I print a web page from Safari, it will use the margin setup from the paper.